# Word for a person who acts like you

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the proper word for someone who acts like you, or is doing the same thing you are doing? I was thinking about *role playing*, but it sounded very out of place.

Comment: As you can see from the many answers posted so far, it is not clear what exactly you have in mind. Please provide further details, a sample sentence, a part of speech, really anything that helps make this a clear question with a single clear answer. Why is that someone acting like you? And to what end? Is it considered a good thing or a bad thing? Considered by whom? If "role playing" sounds very out of place, what exactly is the place it sounds very out of?

Answer (score 1):

we used to call those people **copy-cats**.

> (esp. in children's use) a person who copies another's behavior, dress, or ideas.>

(I was young once.)

Answer (score 0):

**Mimic**

Can be used to describe someone who copies/imitates others. I dont think there is a word which specifically applies to mean someone copying oneself.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call that person an [*impersonator*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impersonator):

> To assume the character or appearance of, especially fraudulently

Answer (score 0):

**Façade** might be another possibility as well.

Answer (score 0):

It can be "mimic" or "copycat"

Answer (score -1):

*ape, aper, echoer, echoist, mimic* (already suggested), *mimicker, mocker, mockingbird,* …

In general, most synonyms of ***imitator***.